# How to set report dates automatically for %str arguments

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm compiling order data using a program that has already been built, but am trying to update a section of the code to take today's date minus 61 days and plus 56 days for the respective start and end dates, rather than a manually typed in date as shown below. The current, functional code as well as one of my attempts is below.

The current format that is working and executing is:

```
/* Set report dates (dd-mm-yyyy) */
%let fore_start = %str(08-SEP-2019);
%let fore_end = %str(03-JAN-2020);
```

I'm attempting to build something like:

```
/* Set report dates (dd-mm-yyyy) */
%let fore_start = %str(TODAY()-61);
%let fore_end = %str(TODAY()+56);
```

I'm looking for help devising a syntactically sound line to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is a "%str()" argument?

Comment: Do you really need the values to have macro quoting?  If so then use the %QSYSFUNC() function instead of the %SYSFUNC() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%let fore_start = %sysfunc(putn(%eval(%sysfunc( today() ) - 61), ddmmyyd10.) );
%let fore_end = %sysfunc(putn(%eval(%sysfunc( today() ) + 56), ddmmyyd10.) );
```

It looks like there's a lot there, but it really isn't. Removing all of the syntax of macro language and converting it into data step functions, here's all you are doing:

```
fore_start = put(today() - 61, ddmmyyd10.);
fore_end   = put(today() + 56, ddmmyyd10.);
```

There are a few things at play:

1. In macro language, SAS functions such as `putn` and `today()` need to both be enclosed with `%sysfunc()`. `%sysfunc()` is your connection to SAS system functions and the macro facility.
2. `%eval` will subtract two integers from each other.
3. `putn`, another SAS function, will convert the resulting SAS date into your desired format of `ddmmyyd10.`. `putn` is required for macro language instead of `put`.

Answer (score 0):

The date representations you show as being kept in macro variables `fore_start` and `fore_end` are actually `dd-mmm-yyyy`, or format `DATE11.`

The `%sysfunc` marco function will invoke a DATA step function and optionally format the result.  The `INTNX` function will perform date arithmetic.

```
%let fore_start = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY, %sysfunc(today()), -61), DATE11);
%let fore_end   = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY, %sysfunc(today()), +56), DATE11);
```